# Counting the number of minimal connected supergraphs of an arbitrary disconnected digraph

Tags: combinatorics, proof-verification, graph-theory, combinatorial-proofs, directed-graphs

To start by "connected" in the context of directed graphs, more formally I mean "weakly-connected" in addition by "minimal" I am using the term with respect to the subgraph relation. With that said for any disconnected digraph $G=(V,E)$ we can always find a connected digraph $H=(V,E')$ on the same vertex set $V$ with $E\subseteq E'$ so that $H\supseteq G$ is a connected supergraph of $G$ this can be done by adding arcs to $G$ that connect all of its connected components to form our new directed graph $H$
For example one can visualize this process by my crudely drawn drawn diagram in microsoft-paint:

[image]

However the digraph $H$ shown above is not *minimal* with respect to the subgraph relation, because I could have added less arrows to form another connected digraph $H'$ satisfying $G\subseteq H'\subset H$ in particular I could remove one of the two arrows connecting two of the components in $H$ to get $H'$.

Now I want to count the number of *minimal, connected, supergraphs* of any dissconected graph $G$. Or more formally if for any dissconected graph $G$ one defines a set $Q$ as follows:

$$Q=\small \{D\supseteq G:\left(D\text{ is weakly connected}\right)\land \left(\text{For any digraph }H\text{ we have }G\subseteq H\subseteq D\implies H=D\right)\}$$

Then I want to find the value of $|Q|$, now this shoudn't be hard and I think I know the answer. Yet I'm unsure if I made a slight error in my reasoning. I think $|Q|=2^{|S|-1}|S|!\prod_{C\in S}|\mathcal{V}(C)|$

Where $S$ is the set of connected components in $G$. My reasoning was basically first if we partition the set $V=\mathcal{V}(G)$ into the family $\mathcal{F}=\{\mathcal{V}(C):C\in S\}$ then now if we take any set of distinct representatives from $\mathcal{F}$ we can form a path $P$ of length $|S|-1$ by connecting them together by $|S|-1$ arrows, where the graph $G\cup P$ should be a minimal, connected supergraph as clearly we see $G\subseteq G\cup P$ and removing any of the arrows from $P$ should dissconect $G\cup P$ with that said there are exactly $\prod_{C\in S}|\mathcal{V}(C)|$ distinct representives we can choose from where each should form a different path $P$, moreover when constructing any path we have to order the vertices and since there are $|S|$ of them there will be $|S|!$ different orderings, lastly as each path is directed and by swapping the direction of any arrow in any of the paths this will still leave $G\cup P$ connected thus because there are $|P|=|S|-1$ arcs in our path digraph $P$ we see the number of digraphs formed by swapping the direction of each arc is $2^{|S|-1}$ so there should be exactly $2^{|S|-1}|S|!\prod_{C\in S}|\mathcal{V}(C)|$ different minimally connected supergraphs of $G$. Or equivalently  $|Q|=2^{|S|-1}|S|!\prod_{C\in S}|\mathcal{V}(C)|$. So is this correct? Or have I made an error somewhere in my reasoning? Any help/corrections etc. would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your approach correctly, you are missing a rather big chunk of cases, namely these, where the new connections form a tree rather than just a path. To simplify the problem I would suggest the following:

1. Create a multigraph $\mathcal{G}$ such that its vertices correspond to (weakly) connected components of your graph.
2. Between any pair $(v_1, v_2)$ of vertices $\mathcal{G}$ add labeled edges, where labels are $S_1 \times S_2$ where $S_i$ is the set of vertices representing the connected component of $G$ corresponding to vertex $v_i$ (and the reverse direction will be handled when adding edges for pair $(v_2, v_1)$).
3. Count the number of spanning trees in this multigraph with labeled edges.

If your original graph $G$ has $k$ connected components, this approach gives you the following formula:

$$\sum_{T \in \mathcal{T}_k}\ \ \prod_{\{i,j\} \in T, i < j}2\cdot|S_i|\cdot |S_j| = 2^{k-1}\sum_{T \in \mathcal{T}_k}\ \ \prod_{\{i,j\} \in T, i < j}|S_i|\cdot |S_j|$$
where $\mathcal{T}_k$ is the set of undirected [labeled trees](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LabeledTree.html) on $k$ vertices (the last equality comes from the fact that you always have $k-1$ edges, and each of these can be in one of two directions).

I hope this helps $\ddot\smile$

Comment: Forgot about connecting them with anything but orientations of paths dumb mistake lol. Okay so it looks like I just need to consider adding those polytrees on $k$ vertices where each vertex is an element of a connected component right? Where by a polytree I mean any orientation of an undirected tree.

Comment: @Ethan You could consider these polytrees, but it's easier to encode the direction in the label of the edge, that is, do undirected edges in the tree, and then multiply the number of labels by two (I've made an edit to make it more clear).

Comment: Won't many of the products appearing in the summation $\prod_{\{i,j\} \in T, i < j}|S_i|\cdot |S_j|$ have the same value?

Comment: I.e. can I write for some $n\in \mathbb{N}$ with integers $1\leq r\leq n$ and subsets $\mathcal{T}_{k,r}\subseteq \mathcal{T}$ that: $$2^{k-1}\sum_{T \in \mathcal{T}_k}\ \ \prod_{\{i,j\} \in T, i < j}|S_i|\cdot |S_j|\\=2^{k-1}\sum_{r=1}^{n}\left(\sum_{T\in \mathcal{T}_{k,r}}f(r)\right)=2^{k-1}\sum_{r=1}^{n}f(r)\left(\sum_{T\in \mathcal{T}_{k,r}}1\right)=2^{k-1}\sum_{r=1}^{n}f(r)|\mathcal{T}_{k,r}|$$
Where I let $f(r)$ be whatever constant value the product $\prod_{\{i,j\} \in T, i < j}|S_i|\cdot |S_j|$ takes on for all $T\in \mathcal{T}_{k,r}$.

Also thanks I really appreciate your help.

Comment: @Ethan It depends on how do you plan to generate all these trees. If you are going to use some black box, then I would skip the optimization until I have a proof that this is an actual issue (i.e. you need to do profiling). If you are going to generate the trees yourself, perhaps recursively, then the partially-generated trees will give you a good structure to group your computations. I need to stress that it is _really easy_ to make a mistake (this question being a case in point), so start with almost-brute-force and as you upgrade your code, compare it to the previous version.

Comment: Don't worry about trying to find a proof dtldarek, you've helped me an enormous amount already. I sorta assumed the question would have just sat there for a while or gone unanswered, as it seems it takes longer to find experts like yourself :) in the subject (not that this is a very complex problem, but I can only assume from your tag count graph-theory/combinatorics is your specialty lol).